# PrimeFaces in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I am a beginner in Java Web Applications and I read some information [here](http://www.primefaces.org/) on how to start use `primefaces` and as a result I added `PrimeFaces` components to my page as `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` and also added the `primefaces-5.0.jar` to my classpath:

```
MyProject->Java_Resources->Libraries->primefaces-5.0.jar
```

I read that I had to add `primefaces-5.0.jar` to `WEB-INF->lib->primefaces-5.0.jar` and I did it, but I couldn't work with `primefaces`. I ran my project and neither of `primefaces` didn't show and also I didn't see any warnings and errors. Do you know any solutions to my problem?

Comment: http://qussay.com/2013/09/14/create-jsf-2-2-maven-project-with-primefaces-3-5-using-eclipse/  if you wanna work with maven.

Comment: Thanks for response but  I don't want to work with maven what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Redeploy the application all over again from scratch after you add the PrimeFaces jar.

Comment: ok maybe this tutorial can help u. http://kein-java-learning-path.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/creating-blank-jsf-primefaces-project.html

Comment: some code examples:http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/primefaces/code/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Jsf component libraries which called jsf-imp.jar and jsf-api.jar and should make configuration on web.xml. You should watch the Jsf+Primefaces Tutorial for beginners.Here is good understandable tutorial for you. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4NawR70uT0